# Problem with using scanf function under stm32

Tags: c, stm32

I've came across on some interesting thing during use of sscanf() for STM32F437:

```
uint8_t var;
st = sscanf(&line[off], "%x", &var);
st = sscanf(&line[off], "%hhx", &var);
```

When I'm trying to compile first line I get suggestion from gcc to use "%hhx" instead of "%x". But when I changed this line to the second one - suggestion from gcc disappeared, but the result of scanning is wrong.

When &line[off] points to following string: 52 then the first scanf(..."%x"...) is working correctly giving 0x52, but the second scanf(..."%hhx"...) produces result 0x34.

Seems like scanf("..."%hhx"...") interpretes 52 as a decimal value 52 and then converts it to hexadecimal value 0x34.
I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc version 9.2.0.

Did I miss something or this is some bug in scanf()?

Comment: Given `uint8_t var;`, `st = sscanf(&line[off], "%x", &var);` is undefined behavior because `%x` is for the address of an `unsigned int` variable, not the address of a `uint8_t` variable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Yes, I know about it. But why the second line produces wrong result?

Comment: @user2699113 Because the first sscanf bug blew up your memory somehow (`.stack` or `.data` has been overwritten etc) and the program has ceased to exist in a predictable execution environment. Such is the nature of undefined behavior bugs.

Comment: remember that embedded implementations are much simpler and do not support many formats. Try to fucus on the native types, do not use modifiers like `hh` etc etc

Comment: What is your standard library implementation? Are you using newlib? Are you linking with newlib-nano? Do you compile/link with `-lnano` or `-specs=nano.specs`?

Comment: @Lundin we do not know if it is an actual code

Comment: @KamilCuk: yes, I'm using nano.specs.

Comment: Then `hhu` is not supported, let me check. [Indeed](https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-1.0/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/vfwscanf.c#L496)

Comment: @Lundin: Not quite, I'm using only one of those scanfs at a time not both at the same time.

Comment: Anyway just nuke stdio.h from orbit and use `strtoul(buf, NULL, 16)`.

Answer (score 2):

- `%x` without a prefix before the `x` means scanf is expecting a pointer to `unsigned int`
- `%hh` is used for `signed char` or `unsigned char`.
- `%hhx` is used for `signed char` or `unsigned char` in hex format.
- `"%"SCNu8` is used for scanning `uint8_t`.
- `"%"SCNx8` is used for `uint8_t` in hex format.
- `uint8_t` is most likely 100% equivalent to `unsigned char` on any system.

This means that here `"%x", &var` you lie to the compiler and (assuming 32 bit CPU) you tell it "go ahead and read 32 bit large integer), then pass a memory address where only 8 bits of valid data are stored. This is undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Speculating about why undefined behavior bugs manifest themselves in a certain way for your specific system is rather meaningless.

Instead, do this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uint8_t var;
st = sscanf(&line[off], "%"SCNx8, &var);
```

---

Please note that `sscanf` is a terribly slow and dangerous function and should not be used on embedded systems. Always use `strtoul` instead.

Comment: `"%"PRIx8` in small embedded uC implementtion?

Comment: @P__J__ `stdio.h` shouldn't be used in production code, least of all in embedded systems. But that's another story.

Comment: Yes, I've already used strtoul instead and it is working properly. Regarding "%"PRIx8 I get error from gcc: error: expected ')' before 'PRIx8'.

Comment: @user2699113 Sorry, it should be `SCNx8`! printf and scanf use different specifiers for the stdint.h types.

Answer (score 2):

You are linking against what is commonly refereed as "newlib-nano". Nano version of newlib comes with limited support from the standard library - it doesn't support all C99 *length modifiers*, like `ll` or `hh` in both `printf` and `scanf`.

The solution is to link against full implementation of newlib, so remove `-specs=nano.specs` or similar from the linking options, or don't use `hh` *length modifier* when compiling with newlib-nano or use other method of converting a string to an integer.

Comment: If that's the case then the correct solution is probably to stick with what the OP have, a freestanding implementation lib, and adapt the code accordingly to suit freestanding (embedded) systems.